# Link to export data from HTML table to excel. VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I have a asp.net web page that has various pieces of data on it.  One of those is a standard html table. 10 columns by 5 rows.  I want to place a link below the table that allows the user to click on it and it will export the data from the table into an excel sheet.

Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried anything? raed anything?

Comment: yes I have for the past few hours but not getting anywhere at all.

Comment: You are not likely to get an answer if you just say hey i need this, how can i do it. you have to show what is not working and what have you tried.

Comment: What have you tried so far? After all, you should be able to point Excel at the webpage and it can suck the data in itself, which might be a simpler solution than generating an XLSX file on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to export the data i am presuming that the data is dynamic, from a database? On that assumption why not display the data in either a GridView or an ASP table? This way you will be better able to export the data.

If you are dynamically creating the table from code then i guess thats different, but you havent stated how your generating the page.

Exporting Controls to excel: Just change Gridview1 to the id of the control you want to export. Either your ASP table or your gridview ID.

```
 Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    Dim frm As HtmlForm = New HtmlForm()

    Page.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportFromWebPage.xls")
    Page.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Page.Response.Charset = ""
    Page.EnableViewState = False
    frm.Attributes("runat") = "server"
    Controls.Add(frm)
    frm.Controls.Add(GridView1)
    frm.RenderControl(hw)
    Response.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.End()
```

-Edit. Ive shown my naivety here and just assumed this wouldn't work with a native html table. I thought id try it and it actually will work. Just run your table at server and give it an ID then replace `gridview1` with the id you've given your HTML table.

Answer (score 1):

im just going to put some articles you can use or other answers but googling html table to excel you can find some answers.

[html table to excel using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301223/html-table-to-excel-using-jquery)
[How to export html table to excel using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566831/how-to-export-html-table-to-excel-using-javascript)

Comment: thanks for at least attempting to assist me, I have googled the issue but I will explore your links.  As you can see from my account I am very new here so apologies if my post annoys you but I have to say you dont instill confidence in the site if you mark down a post from a new member so quickly.  My experience so far of most forums towards noobs is awful.  I understand we need educating on how best to post etc but at least give us a grace period.  ill probably get banned or at least marked down for this.

Comment: The expectation on this site is that you have already tried a few things and you are stuck. Most users on SO, who have been here for a while will seem a little irritated if you ask an open-ended question that makes it sound like you haven't even tried and you think this is goog or something.  There are lots of good questions/answers already posted here.  You just need to persevere a little more and you will find an answer pretty easily.  Hang in there user2050577.

Comment: i didn't downvote i just pointed you that it was not a good question and that you have to try before comming here for an answer.